# Finding out memory footprint size

Tags: linux, memory

I would like to be able to restart a service when it is using too much memory (this is related to a bug in a third party library)

I have used this to limit the amount of memory that can be requested:

```
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (128*1024*1024, 128*1024*1024))
```

But the third party library gets stuck in a memory allocation busyloop failing and re-requesting memory. So I want to be able to, in a thread, poll the current size of the memory of the process.

Language I'm using is python, but a solution for any programming language can be translated into python code, provided it's viable and sensible on linux.

Comment: can you tell us which library to avoid?

Comment: Hah, good call. No, I can't. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is a service you can run to monitor external processes. All you need to do is dump your pid to a file for monit to read. People often use it to monitor their web server. One of the tests monit can do is for total memory usage. You can set a value and if your process uses too much memory it will be restarted. Here's an example monit config

```
check process yourProgram
       with pidfile "/var/run/YOUR.pid"
       start program = "/path/to/PROG.py" 
       stop program = "/script/to/kill/prog/kill_script.sh"
       restart if totalmem is greater than 60.0 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I came up with. Seems to work properly, and avoids too much string parsing. The variable names I unpack come from `proc(5)` man page, and this is probably a better way of extracting the OS information than string parsing `/proc/self/status`.

```
def get_vsize():
    parts = open('/proc/self/stat').read().split()
    (pid, comm, state, ppid, pgrp, session, tty, tpgid, flags, minflt, cminflt,
     majflt, cmajflt, utime, stime, cutime, cstime, counter, priority, timeout,
     itrealvalue, starttime, vsize, rss, rlim, startcode, endcode, startstack,
     kstkesp, kstkeip, signal, blocked, sigignore, sigcatch, wchan,
    ) = parts[:35]
    return int(vsize)

def memory_watcher():
    while True:
        time.sleep(120)
        if get_vsize() > 120*1024*1024:
            os.kill(0, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the current memory usage using the `/proc` filesystem.

The format is `/proc/[pid]/status`. In the `status` virtual file you can see the current VmRSS (resident memory).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid reading /proc/self/status (/proc/self is the currently running process) but if I cannot do anything else, I guess I can do that.